# leaflet.draw questions - edit without draw toolbar

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've been playing with leaflet for a couple of weeks now and I have some questions.

I want a map that can have only 1 polyline and multiple markers.  This polyline and makers are to be added using custom buttons - not the leaflet.draw toolbar.

I want another button that toggles edit mode to allow for editing the polyline and moving the markers.

1. Can I have a "drawControl" on a map without actually adding the draw toolbar to the map?
2. Can I enable/disable polyline editing after an polyline has been created using this.polylineDrawer = new L.Draw.Polyline(this.map)?
3. Can I end drawing a polyline with the use of a custom button rather than re-clicking on the last point on the polyline?

Thanks

Comment: Hi bro! check it https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/129